# EditView must contain data to further process

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout

I have a `EdidText` and a `Button` in a `Fragment`. When I click the `Button` i want to checks whether the `EditText` is empty or not. If is empty I want to return an error message, If notEmpty means move to other `fragments` or something further process.

I previously search the solution for my problem, but mostly I found the solution like ,

```
if(textView.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
      textView.setError("something");
} else {
     //do something;
}
```

The above code worked correctly, but what I ask, how to do this in a layout not programmatically.

I want to know is this is achieved through the layout xml file or not. If possible means please give me an example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is way to do this through `XML`. Since `EditText` value is changed during runtime.

Comment: there is no way to check the EditText in xml only. whether or not you will still use Java code to move to other fragments

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez okay, thanks for your kind response

Comment: Why you want to use it in layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set an error in with XML.

you need to set it in the onCreate of your fragment. This way you won't see the difference if it is set in xml or in code.

You could write your own EditText and add an extra style attribute "error". After that you need to use your own EditText and again set the error in the onCreate.

Create a new class and extend it from EditText like this:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyEditText);
        String error = a.getString(R.styleable.MyEditText_error);
        a.recycle();
        setError(error);
    }
}
```

In Attr add this:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyEditText">
    <attr name="error" format="reference|string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

After that you will need to always use MyEditText

Answer (score 0):

Check it with this code

```
editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()
```

Comment: please fully read my question sir/ma'am, I dont want to do programatically, instead using xml files

Comment: There is no way to do it in xml, xml cannot see whether edittext is empty or not.